# Sqlite: Fetching records where 1 column exists more than once

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+--------+
|  Food   | Color  |
+---------+--------+
| apple   | green  |
| banana  | yellow |
| salad   | green  |
| lemon   | yellow |
| coconut | brown  |
+---------+--------+
```

Based on the `Color` column, I would like to fetch those records where the `Color` column exists more than once.

In my example, the record `apple`, `banana`, `salad` and `lemon` should be fetched, but not `coconut` (because the color `brown` exists only once).

But I am not sure what the select statement would be.

I was thinking about something like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE COUNT(color) > 1`, but this is not right, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of rows for each color, you would need grouping:

```
SELECT color,
       COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY color;
```

To get only those colors with multiple entries, you have to put a filter on the aggregated results, with HAVING:

```
SELECT color,
       COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY color
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

These color values can then be used to filter the original table:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE color IN (SELECT color
                FROM MyTable
                GROUP BY color
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```